# Animated gif on overlay

Tags: html, css

I have this image

[image]

and I have this css

```
#loadingSpinnerBackground {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: #000000 url('http://i.imgur.com/HEAD5PU.gif') center no-repeat;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

and I'm trying to use is to show on an overlay, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jM6Ch/)

But the gif does not show the "LOADING" text on the overlay. Is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it's now showing because I changed the background. (Edited because I think they want answers to sound professional)

```
background: red url('http://i.imgur.com/HEAD5PU.gif') center no-repeat;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jM6Ch/1/)

Comment: Haha I've done what's being asked. But I get a downvote? :D Why?